# Is it possible to observe a partially-constructed object from another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, memory-model

I've often heard that in the .NET 2.0 memory model, writes always use release fences. Is this true? Does this mean that even without explicit memory-barriers or locks, it is impossible to observe a partially-constructed object (considering reference-types only) on a thread different from the one on which it is created? I'm obviously excluding cases where the constructor leaks the `this` reference.

For example, let's say we had the immutable reference type:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Would it be possible with the following code to observe any output other than "John 20" and "Jack 21", say "null 20" or "Jack 0" ?

```
// We could make this volatile to freshen the read, but I don't want
// to complicate the core of the question.
private Person person;

private void Thread1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var personCopy = person;

        if (personCopy != null)
            Console.WriteLine(personCopy.Name + " " + personCopy.Age);
    }
}

private void Thread2()
{
    var random = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        person = random.Next(2) == 0
            ? new Person("John", 20)
            : new Person("Jack", 21);
    }
}
```

Does this also mean that I can make all shared fields of deeply-immutable reference-types `volatile` and (in most cases) just get on with my work?

Comment: I don't see what bearing the memory model has on this question.  Thread 2 only ever assigns fully constructed Person objects, so how could you ever observe a partially constructed one?

Comment: @Peter Ruderman  because the memory model says you can (or can't)

Comment: Because if the constructor returns a pointer to the object under construction before the construction is finished you could see a half generated object. With out of order execution by a cpu it is quite possible for this to hapen without memory barriers. I'm pretty sure .NET guarantees it doesn't but I have no proof :)

Comment: @Peter: One could observe a partially constructed object *if* it were possible to observe the assignment of the field `person` before the assignment of the field(s) of the referenced `Person` object.

Comment: That's not possible in your example.

Comment: @Peter: If it's not possible, I'm asking why it's not possible. If I'm not wrong, at least some (or maybe all) versions of the Java memory model don't offer such guarantees.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644919/net-multithreading-volatile-and-memory-model) help?

Comment: @Peter Ruderman You are assuming data is assigned and code is executed in the order you see it in the source code, which might not be the case on modern cpus (and certainly not on non-cache coherent systems, though .NET doesn't run on such systems yet afaik)

Comment: I'm not assuming any such thing.  I'm well aware of instruction re-ordering, thanks.

Comment: You can create a more easy to verify check. Insert a Sleep between setting to props in the constructor. Then, at least test result will be obvious. Also, you can try to go over your program in a native debugger and see how it is assembled.

Comment: If you really want a definite answer to this, you're probably better off asking someone like Joe Duffy directly.

Comment: What makes you think that the assigment operation (which is atomic for references http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278.aspx) will occur before the constructor has finished its work?

Comment: @Boris: The atomicity of a reference-type assignment only prevents a torn read/write of the reference itself (which is just a managed pointer).

Comment: @Ani ok, but would not the first assignment operation be executed *after* the action is done by the constructor because it's all done in a single thread?

Comment: @Boris: Because unbeknownst to you the C# compiler, JITer, and hardware can alter the order of instructions. This alteration would not effect the logical sequence of the current thread, would effect how other threads perceive things.

Comment: I think that some of the arguments for why double-checked locking is not 100% reliable relates to exactly this scenario. Based on what I've read, my understand is yes, it is possible for this problem to occur in .NET.  I don't know if identifying your member variables as volatile will resolve the issue or not, though.  I am pretty sure that putting lock statements around your person and personcopy assignment statements would prevent the problem, but that's not what you were asking.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov: Actually, that would not work. In fact, it might actually mask a problem because `Thread.Sleep` generates an implicit memory barrier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I've often heard that in the .NET 2.0 memory model, writes always use
>   release fences. Is this true?

It depends on what model you are referring to.

First, let us precisely define a release-fence barrier. Release semantics stipulate that no other read or write appearing before the barrier in the instruction sequence is allowed to move after that barrier.

- The ECMA specification has a relaxed model in which writes do not provide this guarantee.
- It has been cited somewhere that the CLR implementation provided by Microsoft strengthens the model by making writes have release-fence semantics.
- The x86 and x64 architectures strengthen the model by making writes release-fence barriers and reads acquire-fence barriers.

So it is possible that another implementation of the CLI (such as Mono) running on an esoteric architecture (like ARM which Windows 8 will now target) would **not** provide release-fence semantics on writes. Notice that I said it is possible, but not certain. But, between all of the memory models in play, such as the different software and hardware layers, you have to code for the weakest model if you want your code to be truly portable. That means coding against the ECMA model and not making any assumptions.

We should make a list of the memory model layers in play just be explicit.

- Compiler: The C# (or VB.NET or whatever) can move instructions.
- Runtime: Obviously the CLI runtime via the JIT compiler can move instructions.
- Hardware: And of course the CPU and memory architecture comes into play as well.

> Does this mean that even without explicit memory-barriers or locks, it
>   is impossible to observe a partially-constructed object (considering
>   reference-types only) on a thread different from the one on which it
>   is created?

Yes (qualified): If the environment in which the application is running is obscure enough then it might be possible for a partially constructed instance to be observed from another thread. This is one reason why double-checked locking pattern would be unsafe without using `volatile`. In reality, however, I doubt you would ever run into this mostly because Microsoft's implementation of the CLI will not reorder instructions in this manner.

> Would it be possible with the following code to observe any output
>   other than "John 20" and "Jack 21", say "null 20" or "Jack 0" ?

Again, that is qualified yes. But for the some reason as above I doubt you will ever observe such behavior.

Though, I should point out that because `person` is not marked as `volatile` it could be possible that nothing is printed at all because the reading thread may always see it as `null`. In reality, however, I bet that `Console.WriteLine` call will cause the C# and JIT compilers to avoid the lifting operation that might otherwise move the read of `person` outside the loop. I suspect you are already well aware of this nuance already.

> Does this also mean that I can just make all shared fields of
>   deeply-immutable reference-types volatile and (in most cases) get on
>   with my work?

I do not know. That is a pretty loaded question. I am not comfortable answering either way without a better understanding of the context behind it. What I can say is that I typically avoid using `volatile` in favor of more explicit memory instructions such as the `Interlocked` operations, `Thread.VolatileRead`, `Thread.VolatileWrite`, and `Thread.MemoryBarrier`. Then again, I also try to avoid no-lock code altogether in favor of the higher level synchronization mechanisms such as `lock`.

**Update:**

One way I like visualize things is to assume that the C# compiler, JITer, etc. will optimize as aggressively as possible. That means that `Person.ctor` might be a candidate for inlining (since it is simple) which would yield the following pseudocode.

```
Person ref = allocate space for Person
ref.Name = name;
ref.Age = age;
person = instance;
DoSomething(person);
```

And because writes have no release-fence semantics in the ECMA specification then the other reads & writes could "float" down past the assignment to `person` yielding the following valid sequence of instructions.

```
Person ref = allocate space for Person
person = ref;
person.Name = name;
person.Age = age;
DoSomething(person);
```

So in this case you can see that `person` gets assigned before it is initialized. This is valid because from the perspective of the executing thread the logical sequence remains consistent with the physical sequence. There are no unintended side-effects. But, for reasons that should be obvious, this sequence would be disastrous to another thread.

Comment: You're right that I was aware of the possibility of C#/JIT 'hoisting' in my example (does not appear to happen in practice, at least not on C# 4 + .NET 4 on x86), but I did not want to induce any additional effects of `volatile`. But would making the field `volatile` enforce the 'no partially constructed object' guarantee (my guess is yes - the reordering you mention in your update wouldn't happen at any level)?

Comment: @Ani: Yes. The specification for `volatile` says that writes have release-fence semantics so the writes to the `Name` and `Age` fields cannot, per the spec, float down past the assignment to `person`. In other words, the assignment to `person` **must** happen last if using `volatile`. This is one reason why `volatile` does indeed make the double-checked locking pattern work in C# for example.

Comment: Thanks. So can I then infer that my last statement about 'making fields of immutable classes volatile and forgetting about most associated thread-safety issues' is correct for most cases? I do take your point that other synchronization primitives may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You have no hope.  Replace your console write with an error check, set a dozen copies of Thread1() going, use a machine with 4 cores, and you are bound to find a few partially constructed Person instances.  Use the guaranteed techniques mentioned in other answers and comments to keep your program safe.

Both the people who write compilers and the people who create CPU's are, in their quest for more speed, conspiring to make the situation worse.  Without explicit instructions to do otherwise, the compiler people will reorder your code any way they can to save a nanosecond.  The CPU people are doing the same.  Last I read, a single core tends to run 4 instructions simultaneously, if it can.  (And maybe even if it can't.)

Under normal circumstances, you will rarely have a problem with this.  I have found, however, that a minor problem that only appears once every 6 months can be a truely major problem.  And, interestingly, a one-time-in-a-billion problem can happen several times a minute--which is much preferable.  I'm guessing your code will fall in the latter category.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least at the IL level, the constructor is called directly on the stack, with the resulting reference not generated (and able to be stored) until after construction is complete.  As such, it can't be reordered at the (IL) compiler level (for reference types.)

As for the jitter level, I'm not sure, though it would surprise me if it reordered a field assignment and a method call (which is what a constructor is.)  Would the compiler really look at the method and all its possible execution paths to make sure the field is never used by the called method?

Likewise at the CPU level, I would be surprised if reordering would occur around a jump instruction, since the CPU has no way of knowing whether a branch is a 'subroutine call' and will therefore return to the next instruction.  To execute out-of-order would allow for grossly incorrect behavior in the event of 'unconventional' jumps.