# What happens when you read and write an object from multiple threads without protection?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free

I have learned that accessing the same Object from different Threads is not threadsafe and should be protected. Be it thru Locking or 'Interlocked.Exchange' or Immutables or any other means.
This means that the following code is potentially NOT threadsafe because it does not protect access to the shared 'test' object.

My Questions are:

1. Is the following code Safe or Not?
2. If Not, what is the worst that could happen?
3. If Not, is there any exception that is thrown on a dirty Read or Writes that I could catch to prevent the worst?

```
class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Foo =new Random().Next(10000);
    }

    public int Foo;
}

internal class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test =new Test();


        var exitToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)).Token;

        var readerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!exitToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Random Foo: " + test.Foo);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        });


        var writerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!exitToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                test = new Test();

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        });


        await Task.WhenAll(readerTask, writerTask);
    }
}
```

Comment: when working in parallel you should ask yourself: what are the ressources that are shared between those threads and need some protection. This can be pretty much everything, from a file that is written and read from different threads, to a database or whatever. I can't see any shared resource in your codem though.

Comment: I want to point here the attention to assigning a new object to test variable which is not atomic. Therefore it can lead to errors when reading exactly at the same moment.

Comment: Performing a read when a write is incomplete can lead to invalid reads. Performing a write when a write is incomplete can corrupt the data altogether, so it's worse. Multiple reads interleaved is generally fine. If you want to allow multiple reads and exclusive writes, consider the `ReaderWriterLock` class.

Comment: Related questions: [Is it possible to observe a partially-constructed object from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358707/is-it-possible-to-observe-a-partially-constructed-object-from-another-thread) and [Should thread-safe class have a memory barrier at the end of its constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881722/should-thread-safe-class-have-a-memory-barrier-at-the-end-of-its-constructor)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No it is not, because if the program is compiled in Release Mode the runtime can actually not update the variable for optimization reasons. That's why you need volatile or any kind of fencing around Reading and Writing.

Comment: An annoying problem with answering these questions is that the answers cannot be validated experimentally, because the problematic behavior can never appear on commonly used hardware. For example on my PC your program will always run correctly, no matter how many times I try to run it. But it might be possible to crash with a `NullReferenceException` if it runs on less common hardware. Or it can theoretically crash on a machine that doesn't actually exist, but nevertheless its architecture would comply with the weak ECMA memory model specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the following code Safe or Not?

When talking about "safe" it is important to specify what it is "safe" for. Usually when designing a class we have some requirements we want the class to fulfill (sometimes called "invariants"). If these requirements are fulfilled even if the object is used from multiple threads we call it "thread safe". Take a trivial class:

```
public class Incrementer{
  public int Value {get; private set;}
  public void Increment() => Value++;
}
```

We would probably have a requirement that the value should exactly equal the number of times the `Increment` method was called. This requirement would not be fulfilled if it is called concurrently, but that does not mean it will throw an exception, blow up, or crash, just that the value does not match our requirement.

If we change the requirement to be "value > 0 if Increment is called at least one time", then the read-modify-write issue is not relevant, since we only care if the value has been written once.

In your specific example the only variable that is written to and read concurrently is the `test`-variable. Since writing references are atomic we know this will always point to *some* object. There could potentially be issues with reordering when the object is constructed. This could cause the reference to be updated before the actual value has been set, and would therefore be observed as zero. I do not think this would occur with common x86 hardware and software, but the safe version would be to either use a lock, or create the object, issue a memory barrier and then update the reference.

The other potential risk is that the read-thread does not update the reference from memory, and just loads it once and reuses the same value in each iteration. I do not think this could actually occur in this case, since the loop also calls `Task.Delay` and `Console.WriteLine`, and I would expect both of these to issue a memory barriers or something else that ensures a read actually occurs, and that no reordering is done. But I would probably still recommend using a lock or marking the variable as volatile, it is usually a good idea to err on the side of caution.

> If Not, what is the worst that could happen?

In this case, that the same value would always be printed. But as I mentioned above, this will most likely not occur.

> If Not, is there any exception that is thrown on a dirty Read or Writes that I could catch to prevent the worst?

In general, no. Some types *may* throw exceptions if they are used concurrently or from the wrong thread, a typical example would be any UI classes. But this is not something that should be relied upon.

This is also one of the reason why multi threading bugs are so devious, If you are unlucky the only effect is that the value is wrong, and it might not even be obviously wrong, it might just be off a little bit. And if you are even more unlucky it only occur in special circumstances, like when running under full load on a 20 core server, so you might never be able to reproduce it in a development environment.

Comment: *"Since writing references are atomic we know this will always point to some valid, fully constructed, object."* -- This is debatable. Not that writes are atomic, but that the object will always be fully constructed. See [Is it possible to observe a partially-constructed object from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358707/is-it-possible-to-observe-a-partially-constructed-object-from-another-thread)

Comment: "Since writing references are atomic" - I side here with @TheodorZoulias. Why would something like Interlocked.Exchange for references exists if writing a reference variable would be atomic. But everything else sounds good for me.

Comment: @rudimenter references *are* **atomic**, it will be either the old value or the new value, never something in between. Interlocked.Exchange will also issue memory barriers that prevent reordering and other optimizations. So TheodorZoulias has a point that potential reordering could occur, but that is a separate issue from atomic writes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, valid point, I have updated the answer, hope that should cover it.

Comment: @rudimenter Interlocked.Exchange not only assigns new value, it also returns old value (all as an atomic operation), so it's not the same as simple assignment.

Comment: @rudimenter: Interlocked.whatever is also a full memory barrier, giving very strong ordering (like the x86 `lock` prefix, which these functions were designed as wrappers for).  Atomicity just means no tearing of the pointer value itself, it doesn't guarantee ordering wrt. *other* operations (like the writer making the pointed-to data visible before other threads might see the pointer).  And as Evk says, Interlocked.Exchange is an atomic RMW that gives you the old value, not just an atomic store.  That's useful for some algorithms.